# LightGBM tree structure extracting and interpretation

Tags: lightgbm

I'm trying to extract exact tree structure of trees constructed by Light GBM algorithm. I've used `model_dump` for this and I've extracted structure successfully. The tree looks like this (trained on iris dataset):

[image: Tree structure]

I'm having trouble with understanding how to evaluate this tree. [Another topic on Stack Overflow says that leaf value is raw prob. before sigmoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280845/access-trees-and-nodes-from-lightgbm-model). It seems perfectly logical but when I tried to put this value in sigmoid function, probabilities returned by `lightgbm.predict(...)` were different than probabilities calculated based on my tree. Is there any postprocessing hidden inside before `model_dump` that affects those values? What is the correct way to calculate output prob. from those trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iris dataset is multiclass classification. The tree you are showing us is for one class. Depending on the [objective](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#objective) you are using, the postprocessing is not always sigmoid. For multiclass, you need to apply [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) to your raw predictions.