# How to access the linear models in LightGBM for linear_tree=True

Tags: python, lightgbm

It is possible to access the nodes and trees of Light GBM using `model._Booster.dump_model()["tree_info"]` (see that question [Access trees and nodes from LightGBM model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280845/access-trees-and-nodes-from-lightgbm-model)). However, for `linear_tree=True` (https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#linear_tree), at each leaf of each tree a linear model is trained. How can I get the coefficiens and the offset of these linear models?

Answer (score 2):

I found one possibility which is not nice at all but the only one I am aware of. The `_Booster` object possesses a method called `save_model()` which writes all model information into a text file. From that text file you can parse the coefficients and constants of the linear models at each tree.